# dropdownlist in footer row of gridview being clear on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using a `dropdownlist` in footer row of `gridview`(`ASP.Net`) and I fill that on `rowdatabound` event,first time it works fine but when the form is postbacked,dropdown gets cleared.

It can be solved by refilling it on each postback,but I want that only single time code binding call fulfill my need,
means is there any way to stop from being null on postback.

looking for your kind solutions and suggestions
Thnx in advance......

Supriya

Code:

protected void gvProjects_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

```
    try
    {

        if (gvProjects.Rows.Count > 0 && e.Row.RowIndex != -1)
        {
            string proj_Id = Convert.ToString(gvProjects.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value);
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                DropDownList ddlProject = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlProject");
                if (ddlProject != null && ddlProject.Items.Count == 0)
                {
                    objMaster.FillProjects(ddlProject);
                    ddlProject.SelectedValue = proj_Id;
                }
            }

        }
    }
    catch (Exception excep)
    {
        lbl_msg.Text = excep.Message;
    }
}
```

It's called whenever the grid is binded,can it be avoided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this code you will avoid filling the dropdownlist located in the gridview footer in each rowdatabound:

```
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType != DataControlRowType.Footer)
        {
            //do the binding for the normal rows
        }
    }
```

As you can see, the rowdatabound will be only executed on the header and normal rows but not in the footer.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {               
            FillDropdown();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Mark answer as Accepted answer.